# Why the browser don't display my Calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I found the code to implements a Calendar in HTML with js

It is here: http://webdesignandsuch.com/add-a-calendar-date-picker-to-a-form-with-jquery/

The my following code, it isn't working.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">                       
            <div class="panel-body">
                Escolha a data do jogo:
                </br>
                </br>

                <form>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">

                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                    });
                </script>
                <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu jogo será às..." />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Include the link and scripts in the `<head>` and maybe add the type="text" in your input

Comment: it works fine - http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/NNjGZd

Comment: why don't you show the whole page then?

Comment: Could it be a browser issue?  I pasted your code into an HTML file on a web server and opened it.  The datepicker worked fine for me.

Comment: I pasted the full code on web server and worked perfectally.. can be some variable into my css classes (bootstrap)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you pasted here works fine. I think you have a js issue before the `datepicker()` call. You can try to check your browser console log or paste more code here.

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
        <div class="panel panel-default">                       
            <div class="panel-body">
                Escolha a data do jogo:

                <form>
              

                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                    });
                </script>
                <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu jogo será às..." />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: tranks for answer, i found the problem. was duplicatted the code that was in my bootstrap:
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>